# Layer substraction

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

I drew the following vectorial img with photoshop
[image]

However, i want the mask to be white, not all transparent. When i modify the stroke background, it hides the eyes and the mouth
I don't want this to happen, here is the example

[image]

What should i do ? thanks to all

Comment: This probably is a stupid question but did you change the eyes and mouth color to black (or any other color other than white) before adding the white background ? You can't actually see white strokes on white background...

Comment: They don't even have a background, they just have an outline.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

1. Duplicate the shape layer
2. Convert to a selection
3. Fill the selection with white
4. Put it above or below the shape layer

It may be just a workaround but may be worth experimenting.